# What does "Hamlet stool" mean?

Tags: meaning, books

I have read this in Maugham's "Theatre":

> She wrote her letters at a satinwood desk, seated on a gilt Hamlet stool.

<sup>[[Source (PDF)]](http://content.ikon.mn/banners/2015/4/9/1472/william-somerset-maugham-theatre.pdf)</sup>

What does it mean?

I have googled it and found tens of images and no formal definition.
As there are so many various images, with 3 legs and 4 legs, with and without back, high and low, I really cannot understand what exactly does it mean, what kind of chair it is and why it is called so, what is its relation to Hamlet.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no evidence has been supplied to counter @Stuart F's claim that this is merely a brand name. Google search results strongly bolster that claim.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> **Curule**. Among the Romans, a sort of folding stool without a back, conveyed in a chariot, which only the chief magistrates were permitted
> to sit upon; sometimes called "**Hamlet stool**". [A. C. Passmore;
> *Handbook of Technical Terms Used in Architecture and Building and Their Allied Trades*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Handbook_of_Technical_Terms_Used_in_Arch/NawaAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22hamlet%20stool%22&pg=PA102&printsec=frontcover) (1904)

[Curule images (Google)](https://www.google.com/search?q=curule&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS911US911&sxsrf=AOaemvLht9Tp2bCfXbRBiS8YrhnHtGmD6w:1631974594735&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiskYGQ24jzAhWcSTABHUEWDZkQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1378&bih=716&dpr=0.9)

---

> The photographer's first duty is the production of a likeness...and
> the face and clothed figure of the client should be considered before
> the Grecian pillar or the **Hamlet stool**.
> ...
> Hundreds of books have been written, and endless controversies waged
> round the subject of hamlet's mentality. There can be little doubt
> about his state of mind, for a youth spent among **Hamlet stools**
> would make anyone dotty.  [J. Effel; "With a
> Portraitist in the Studio," *Bulletin of Photograpy*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Bulletin_of_Photography/2CAoAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22hamlet%20stool%22&pg=PA707&printsec=frontcover), p.708 and p.710 (1922)

> In the drawing room there were occasional chairs, settees, Juliet
> seats, **Hamlet stools**.  [L. W. Peat; *Grandma Did it this Way*](https://www.google.com/search?q=peat%20%22grandma%20did%20it%20this%20way%22%20%22hamlet%20stools%22&biw=1128&bih=615&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AOaemvLw4jG-2OHOiVlA9hk5W8uh-43QGQ%3A1631976463061&ei=D_xFYZXeAsvp_QbViJm4Aw&oq=peat%20%22grandma%20did%20it%20this%20way%22%20%22hamlet%20stools%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3691.15768.0.16000.48.48.0.0.0.0.108.4026.44j4.48.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.32.2675...0i512k1j0i10k1j33i299k1j33i10k1.0.pq14kmm0x1M) (1950)

> This sort of undifferentiated recycling of stock material from a
> theater's warehouse was stoutly opposed by the romantic theorists of
> the early twentieth century and by the realists who followed them,
> both of which envision a stage in which every element would be
> selected to contribute to the total artistic vision of each production
> and not utilized again. Nevertheless, custom and economy made this a
> vision unrealizable for most theaters. Even at the end of the
> nineteenth century, Nemirovich-Danchenko, Stanislavsky's codirector at
> the Moscow Art Theatre, reports that the sort of properties Wilkinson
> might have call "old-acquaintances" had by no means disappeared. Moreover, audiences had become so familiar with
> certain of these that they, like certain actors associated with
> particular types of roles, brought with them certain expectations with
> each new appearance. Thus, Nemirovich-Danchenko reports, a certain
> tall lamp with a yellow shade became associated with "cozy love
> passages," while **a curule chair in a "Gothic/Renaissance style," was
> in fact referred to by at least one director as the "culture chair."**
> [Marvin Carlson; *Shattering Hamlet's Mirror: Theatre and Reality*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Shattering_Hamlet_s_Mirror/MplFDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=hamlet%20curule&pg=PA91&printsec=frontcover)

---

**Hamlet seat**

> Front and Side Elevations of a **Hamlet Seat** [P. N. Hasluck; *The
> Handyman's Guide: Essential Woodworking Tools and Techniques*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Handyman_s_Guide/AjZ-EvlC38MC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22hamlet%20seat%22&pg=PA706&printsec=frontcover)
> (Figure caption in the "Drawing Room Furniture" Chapter) (2011)

> **Inlaid Hamlet Seat**, upholstered in rich silk, £2 9 6 [Illustrated ad in *Pall Mall Magazine*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Pall_Mall_Magazine_Extra/aalHAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22hamlet%20seat%22&pg=PP12&printsec=frontcover)
> (1899)

Comment: Good research, and almost certainly the sense used in OP (though rare nowadays).

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curule_seat) has, for 'curule-seat' _19th-century dealers and collectors termed these "Dante Chairs" or "Savonarola Chairs", with disregard to the centuries intervening between the two figures.... The [famous] photo of actor Edwin Booth as Hamlet poses him in a regal cross-framed chair, considered suitably medieval in 1870_'

Comment: It looks like the curule seat, stool, or even [bench](https://www.google.com/search?q=curule+bench&tbm=isch&sxsrf=AOaemvIJ9Gu8HNFnpvnfEfEwW3ZVTmhaSQ:1631990683913&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj32_aHl4nzAhX3QzABHaFCD7QQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=827&bih=451&dpr=1.5) (a love-curule for two??) has stayed around and just changed name from period to period.

Comment: Wikipedia also has the photo of [Hamlet in a Hamlet seat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curule_seat#/media/File:Edwin_Booth_Hamlet_1870.jpg) mentioned by @EdwinAshworth.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Indeed, however the caption has *curule chair*. I added the two citations for *Hamlet seat* because the illustrations use that name. In other words, if we can't link the name Hamlet to the furniture, we're back at square one, with Hamlet sitting on a curule coincidently made by Hamlet furniture, Ltd. Clearly all that sitting by the play's character rubbed off on the stool/seat :-)

Comment: It won't let me add one, but a picture would certainly enhance this answer.

Answer (score 9):

If we search for the word "stage" in the novel (*Theatre*) using [the PDF document linked in the question](http://content.ikon.mn/banners/2015/4/9/1472/william-somerset-maugham-theatre.pdf), there are 70 instances. The name Hamlet is mentioned 8 times:

- seated on a gilt Hamlet stool
- Over the chimney-piece was an old copy of Lawrence's portrait of Kemble as Hamlet
- "I wonder if I'm too old to play Hamlet. Siddons and Sarah Bernhardt played him.”
- "Don't be idiotic, Charles. I wouldn't play the Queen. I'd play Hamlet." etc.

I haven't read the story but it appears to be centred around an actress whose ambition is to play the role of Hamlet on stage. It's my assumption that the gilded stool refers to a rather expensive-looking stool the theatre used as a **stage prop** in the play Hamlet.  In this instance the "Hamlet" is a (proper) noun adjunct acting as an adjective.

On Google images I searched for "19th century gilt stool" as the story was first published in 1937. It is possible that the stool in question resembled the one below; it is British-made and certainly looks theatrical.

The renowned auction house, Christie's, describes the following [piece of furniture](https://www.christies.com/en/lot/lot-6221253):

> an English green-painted and **parcel-gilt stool** [partially gilded stool] possibly early 19th century, after a design by Thomas Hope

[image: AN ENGLISH GREEN-PAINTED AND PARCEL-GILT STOOL]

Comment: Sorry, I don't think so. In the quote above the main character, Julia is sitting in her home, in her own study, writing a letter.

Comment: @Flot2011 maybe being a theatrical actress, Julia wanted that piece of furniture from the stage production of Hamlet in her bedroom, after all the stool was gilded in gold....

Comment: The brand name theory looks far more likely.

Comment: The stool may have been a prop acquired after the production had concluded, or it may have been another stool, similar in style. Either way the description would be appropriate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I would agree if a brand name has been used for other furniture in the story.

Comment: Might be worth noting that the [Russian version](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD/l0jcDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22hamlet+stool%22&pg=PA14) of the book explicitly states, in a footnote, that the Hamlet stool was _a stool which had been part of the stage props in the play "Hamlet"_

Comment: @KillingTime DjinTonic has unearthed a solid reference (Passmore) strongly suggesting that's a small part of the answer. Nowadays, a 'Hamlet stool' would probably default to 'a stool in X's _Hamlet_ range'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth so you were wrong to make a hasty judgment based on your disapproval of my answer. BTW mine was the first upvote for DjinTonic's answer, their references are an excellent find. I am well pleased.

Comment: I judged the lack of substantiation in the answer. My initial research showed at least 95% trivial usage of 'Hamlet stool', and only a reference of such solidity as the Passmore one merits an answer here.  Without substantiating references, we'll be explaining arbitrary strings such as 'Mars bars' and 'plastic cups'. // Note that the judgement was on probabilistic ('far more likely': Maugham died as recently as 1965)  rather than veridical grounds).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Perhaps it's best to retract your vote to close the question. It's been closed once, then the OP edited and provided context and evidence of research. I like to think my theory and idea sparked DjinTomic's excellent and by far better answer.

Comment: Yes, I've done that. Perhaps it's better to delete this answer. The present 5:6 ratio of votes doesn't reflect the fact that the other answer is correctly researched and almost certainly correct.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Why? It was certainly better than saying that the chair/stool was produced by a manufacturer called Hamlet.  A pity that comment and yours endorsing it have been deleted.

Comment: I merely said it was a better theory (OP doesn't give enough context to judge between possibilities). And I didn't presume to add a guesswork answer.

Comment: And I said it was very unlikely a theatrical actress in the 1930s would have purchased a modern chair in steel and plastic for her bedroom. So, what did I do? I searched for a type of stool that was theatrical-looking and guess what? It's very similar to DjinTonoic's answer , curule stool/seat, which happens to support the image I posted. No, I shan't delete it because where do you think the name Hamlet came from?  :)

Comment: When I search the PDF document for "hamlet", I get only 7 matches.

Comment: @Scott  My search finds 8 matches for Hamlet: **page 4** *gilt hamlet stool*, **p7** *Lawrence's portrait of Kemble as Hamlet*; **p52** (x2) *The Queen in Hamlet*, and *"I wonder if I'm too old to play Hamlet. Siddons and Sarah Bernhardt played him…*; **p153** *She was beginning to feel more and more like Hamlet's mother*; **p158** (x3) *I felt just like Hamlet's mother*, *"Then with hardly a break: I wonder if I'm too old to play Hamlet?"* and *"I wouldn't play the Queen. I'd play Hamlet”*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I just wanted to get back to you: The very last occurrence (“I wouldn't play the Queen. I'd play Hamlet.”, on page 158) is hyphenated (“…  I'd play Ham- let.”), and so Firefox didn’t see it.  Thanks for enumerating the eight mentions, so I could troubleshoot this.